# Python: How to find two equal/closest values between two separate arrays?

Tags: python, comparison

Let's say we have two arrays of equal length:

```
arr1 = (21, 2, 3, 5, 13)
arr2 = (10, 4.5, 9, 12, 20)
```

Which variable from `arr1` is **equal / closest** to a variable from `arr2`?

Looking at these two lists we can easily say that the closest numbers are **4.5** and **5**. I've tried to implement a function that returns two closest values given two lists and it kinda *works* for the examples above, but it is barely a solution because it is not optimal. And you can easily check that the function fails when we slightly change the arrays like this:

```
arr1 = (21, 2, 3, 5, 13)
arr2 = (10, 4.5, 9, 12, 18)
```

the values the function returns are 13 and 18

Here is the function:

```
def get_nearest(arr1, arr2):
    lr = [[0, 0, 0]]
    for x1 in arr1:
        for x2 in arr2:
            r = (x1 / x2 % (x1 + x2))
            print x1, x2, r
            if r <= 1 and r >= lr[0][2]:
                lr.pop()
                lr.append([x1, x2, r])
    return lr
```

Can you come up with a better one?

Comment: For me its seems 5 and 4.5 are closest ?

Comment: you're right, my mistake

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is speed an issue? Do you care about ties?  If not, what about something simple like

```
from itertools import product
sorted(product(arr1, arr2), key=lambda t: abs(t[0]-t[1]))[0]
```

For both

```
arr1 = (21, 2, 3, 5, 13)
arr2 = (10, 4.5, 9, 12, 20)
```

and

```
arr1 = (21, 2, 3, 5, 13)
arr2 = (10, 4.5, 9, 12, 18)
```

this yields

```
(5, 4.5)
```

**Explanation:**

```
product(arr1, arr2) = [(a1, a2) for (a1, a2) in product(arr1, arr2)]
```

yields a list of all `N**2` pairs of numbers:

```
[(21, 10), (21, 4.5), ..., (13, 12), (13, 20)]
```

Then we sort them by the absolute difference (`|a1 - a2|`) using `sorted`. By passing `sorted` the `key` keyword, we tell `sorted` to use the sorting criteria `lambda t: abs(t[0] - t[1])`.  The pair with the smallest absolute difference is placed in the first index of the sorted array, so we can grab it by tacking `[0]` on the end.

**Edit:**

As suggested by Piotr in the comments, you can feed a `key=func` to `min` and `max`, which speeds this up considerably.  Try instead:

```
from itertools import product
min(product(arr1, arr2), key=lambda t: abs(t[0]-t[1]))[0]
```

Comment: nice indeed, but I need some time to understand what's going on here.

Comment: @minerals, I added an explanation.

Comment: You should use max instead of sorted()[0]

Answer (score 7):

This is the fastest algorithm I was able to write, it has n*log(n) complexity which is much faster than naive n*n approach presented in other answers. It sorts arrays before processing ( it is the most time consuming part ) and later tries to minimize the difference (this takes 2*n in the worst case):

```
def closest_array_items(a1, a2):
    if not a1 or not a2:
        raise ValueError('Empty array')
    a1, a2  = iter(sorted(a1)), iter(sorted(a2))
    i1, i2 = a1.next(), a2.next()
    min_dif = float('inf')
    while 1:
        dif = abs(i1 - i2)
        if dif < min_dif:
             min_dif = dif
             pair = i1, i2
             if not min_dif:
                  break
        if i1 > i2:
            try:
                i2 = a2.next()
            except StopIteration:
                break
        else:
            try:
                i1 = a1.next()
            except StopIteration:
                break
    return pair
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> arr1 = (21, 2, 3, 5, 13)
>>> arr2 = (10, 4.5, 9, 12, 20)
>>> for a1 in arr1:
...     for a2 in arr2:
...         if a1 > a2:
...             result.append([a1, a2, a1-a2])
...         else:
...             result.append([a1, a2, a2-a1])
>>> sorted(result, key=lambda i:i[-1])[0][:2]
[5, 4.5]
```

A simple way could be get difference between both arrays and sort them by their difference and get the first element.

```
>>> sorted([[a1,a2,a1-a2] if(a1>a2) else [a1,a2,a2-a1] for a1 in arr1 for a2 in arr2], key=lambda i:i[-1])[0][:2]
[5, 4.5]
```

Answer (score 1):

What about simply saving the difference and the values in each iteration...

```
arr1 = (21, 2, 3, 5, 13)
arr2 = (10, 4.5, 9, 12, 20)

diff = float("inf")

for a1 in arr1:
    for a2 in arr2:
        if abs(a1-a2) < diff:
            diff = abs(a1-a2)
            values = (a1, a2)

print(values)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a function which solves this problem in ~0.01s for an two vectors with the length 1000, 2000:

```
def get_closest_elements(arr_1, arr_2):
    """
    The function finds the two closest elements in two arrays

    Returns
    -------
    idx_1 : int
        index of element in arr_1
    idx_2 : int
        index of element in arr_2
    min_diff : float
        minimal difference between arrays
    """

    # get array with all differences between arrays
    diff_arr = x[:, np.newaxis] - y

    # get absolute value
    diff_arr = np.abs(diff_arr)

    # get minimum difference
    min_diff = np.min(diff_arr)

    # get the indexes for the elements of interest in arr_1 and arr_2
    idx_1, idx_2 = np.where(diff_arr == min_diff)

    return idx_1, idx_2, min_diff


# apply function
x = np.array([21, 2, 3, 5, 13])
y = np.array([10, 4.5, 9, 12, 20])
# n = 1000
# x = np.random.rand(n)
# y = np.random.rand(2*n)

idx_1, idx_2, min_diff = get_closest_elements(x, y)
print "x{} - y{} = {}".format(idx_1, idx_2, min_diff)
```