# Matching two list of numbers by the index of closest value

Tags: arrays, list, algorithm

I know there are already similar questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52798977/), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45349561/), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27239786/)) but they are all in Python and they do not fit what I need.

Given two sorted list, say `1, 6, 13, 21, 28` and `2, 15, 20`. The indices, *without repeating* (unlike link 1 above), of the closest number in the first array are returned, in this case `0, 2, 3`.

The tricky point is, in the case `1, 4, 66, 67, 68, 71` and `68, 68, 68, 82, 82`, returning `2, 3, 4, 5, 1` is more preferable than `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`.

<s>It is possible that the length of the first list < the length of the second list. `1, 7, 11` and `6, 24, 28, 32, 34` should return `0, 1, 2, X, X`, where `X` can be any integer other than 0, 1 and 2. (Both `0, 1, 2, -1, -1` and `0, 1, 2, 3, 4` are acceptable.)</s>

*Edit:* Just swap the two lists and return `0, 1, 2`.

Codes given in C-like languages or pseudocode is preferable.

Any idea better than a brute-force search?

---

### Edit

The given examples may not be the best solutions, e.g. the final (struckthrough) example could return `1, 0, 2` (`1, 0, 2, X, X`) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Let the first array be `a` and the second be `b`.

Let the cost of assigning index `i` to `b[j]` be `abs(a[i] - b[j])`. Then we can find a solution by modelling our problem as an [unbalanced assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) in O(nr<sup>2</sup>) time where *r* is the size of the smallest array and  *n* the biggest.

Comment: Great. But I may get `0, 2, 1, X, X` instead of `0, 1, 2, X, X` in the final example because both results cost the same. (When I use the squared distance instead, the second example got wrong.) Can you give a sample code in C#? Is there any method that does not require a cubic time complexity?